# minitest - pass any argument to expect

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have the following code that I am using to mock a call to a class method:

```
def test_calls_update_profile_job_for_a_lead
  input = ContactInput.new valid_attributes

  mock = MiniTest::Mock.new

  use_case = CreateContact.new user, input, mock

  mock.expect(:perform_async, nil, [user.id, 1, ::Contact])

  use_case.run!

  assert mock.verify
end
```

The problem is that I am having to pass in the specific values -

> [user.id, 1, ::Contact]

to make the test pass.

Is there a way that I don't have to specify the exact values or maybe at least constrain what the arguments are.  I don't want to check the exact arguments, I just want to make sure that the method was called.

Comment: +1  It seems that Minitest makes it impossible to expect without specifying the *exact* values.  In my use case how can I specify the exact value when I am getting a randomly generated UUID?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/MiniTest/Mock.html):

> *args* is compared to the expected args using case equality (ie, the '===' operator), **allowing for less specific expectations**.

For instance,

```
mock = MiniTest::Mock.new
mock.expect(:perform_async, 'goodbye', [Integer, Integer, String])
puts mock.perform_async(1, 1, 'hello')  #=>goodbye 
puts mock.perform_async(1, 1, 1)  #=>MockExpectationError
```

Comment: That beautiful documentation.